# interfaces in Java

Tags: c#, java, interface

In C#, it's common to have methods like this:

```
public IPerson GetPerson()
{
  // do stuff
  return new Person(..);
}
```

where "`IPerson`" is an interface used by `Person`, `SpecialPerson`, etc. In other words, although the method above returns a `Person`, a strategy pattern could be implemented such that a `SpecialPerson` is returned in lieu of a `Person`, provided they all use the `IPerson` interface.

Is this sort of thing possible in Java?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking boils down to: can an interface in Java ("IPerson" in this case) be returned from a method, or passed into a method as a param? When I was doing Java, that didn't seem like a common pattern at all, whereas in .NET world we do it all the time. Just wondering if that was a language limitation.

Comment: Googling for simply "Java interfaces" would have told you that it's pretty much exactly the same in Java.

Comment: @Garrett: of course you can do that. The two languages work exactly the same in that respect.

Comment: Yes. They work in the same way as in C#

Comment: well, what does your java compiler say?

Comment: "When I was doing Java, that didn't seem like a common pattern at all" You worked with bad developers

Comment: "When I was doing Java, that didn't seem like a common pattern at all"... kidding, right? All the while I'm asking myself "Aren't we abusing interfaces, somehow?"

Comment: Note that the Java interface naming convention isn't "IThing" it's more like "Thingable". A chess game might have "Moveable" chess pieces, rather than "IChessPiece". "Knight implements Moveable", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Java has interfaces too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's pretty much the same... For example:

```
// Interface
public interface IPerson {
    public String getName();
}

// Implementation of interface - NB "implements" keyword
public class Person implements IPerson {
    private final String myName;

    public Person(String name) {
        myName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }
}

// Method returning interface
public IPerson getPerson(String name) {
    return new Person(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is pretty much the same, other than Java uses the "implements" keyword for interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java has interfaces just like C#:

```
public interface IPerson {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java equivalent would be:

```
public Person getPerson()
{
  // do stuff
  return new SpecialPerson(..);
}
```

Where `Person` is a Java interface (prefixing interface names with the letter "I" is a convention from COM programming, thus not appropriate for Java).

Comment: I use the I prefix convention in Java so that it's easier to identify file types without having to open them (like in the Eclipse browsser). I also use A for abstract classes. Just helps me sort through things. Nice thing about conventions is that you can use your own.

Comment: If you design right, you should not have to care that you have an interface type or another type.